# Get the absolute path of .app bundle in OS X using swift

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to find the path of where a simple OS X app is running from. I tried

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let path = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
```

but `path` always has value `/`. How do I get the absolute path, such as if the `.app` is executed from `/Users/xxx/sandbox/sample.app` I expect the value `/Users/xxx/sandbox`

is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSBundle`:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent!.path!
```